# Any pdf Library for Laravel that supports Arabic?

Tags: php, laravel-5, dompdf

I have tried alot of Libraries for Pdf with laravel, like Dom Pdf, Mpdf, .. Etc

If any one know a library that supports arabic, or a solution with Dom Pdf, i will appreciate that, cause the letters in DOM Pdf shown in reverse manner.

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried this one? [Laravel PDF](https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf) seems like it was updated recently (less than 6 months ago)

Comment: @Rafael yes i mention that i tried this one also

Comment: Have you considered opening an issue on this one, assuming you tried and it didn't work for you?

Comment: actually no, but i saw a similler opened issues, i spend more than 2 weeks trying to find any solution